# Using process.env commands in windows for the production

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, deployment

I want to test my web application in production mode in windows. Using VS Code command prompt and I have set some values like `$env:KEY = "VALUE"` in the CMD. And I want to access them using `process.env.KEY` in my code. But when I restart my VS Code they all are removed from the `process.env`.
Will anyone provide me the solution for storing them permanently in my pc environment variables or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **.env** file to store your values.

Please go through following link for details:
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786